# Sequences that are contained in a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Prove that $A$ is open iff $\forall x\in A, x_{n} \rightarrow x,$ implies the sequence $x_{n}$ is ultimately in $A$, i.e. There exists $N$ such that $n \geq N \rightarrow x_{n}\in A$

I am having a really hard time understanding how I would prove this, any hints or partial proofs would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for not being able to attempt the proof.

Definition of open: A set $A$ is open iff each of its points is an interior point

Comment: What is your definition of '*open* set'?

Comment: What is your topological space here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  assume we're in a metric space or $\mathbb{R^n}$. If $A$ is open and $x_n\to x$ as in the statement, then by the definition of open there's $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subset A$. By the definition of convergence, $x_n\in B(x,\epsilon)$ for sufficiently large $n$. Conversely, if $x\in A$ is not an interior point, then each ball $B(x,1/n)$ contains some $x_n$ not in $A$, which gives a sequence converging from the complement of $A$ into $A$.

Comment: We haven't learn metric spaces but I understand your proof, just need to read about metric spaces. Thank You

Comment: Sure, just think the whole proof is in real space.